# Is there a way to attach a link to an image that will lead to a random slide within a range?

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-slides

I can't figure out a way to make a link or any interactive piece of a slide show to lead to random range of slides. i.e. You click on an image that will lead you to one slide out of 4-6.

I've tried messing with the hyperlinks to cause you to go to a random slide within a range, but it never worked.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `attach a link to an image that will lead to a random slide within a range`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: On slides you have the option to attack a hyperlink to an image, I was wondering if when you use that hyperlink if it can lead to a random slide like slide 4, 5, or 6.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still imagine your expected situation from `On slides you have the option to attack a hyperlink to an image, I was wondering if when you use that hyperlink if it can lead to a random slide like slide 4, 5, or 6.`. You have an image in the 1st slide, and you want to give the link to another slide in the same Google Slide. At that time, you want to give the link of the random slide. And., you want to ask whether this can be achieved. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes that is mostly correct, sorry that I cannot explain it well. I want that random slide to be only some of the slides though. The link could only go to slides 5 or 6, for example

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, for example, when an image of 1st slide is set as slide page 5, how or when do you want to update the link to another one? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: What I would want is the image of the 1st slide to be randomly set to slide page 5 or 6.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. I can understand `What I would want is the image of the 1st slide to be randomly set to slide page 5 or 6.`. But, for example, when an image of 1st slide is set as slide page 5, how or when do you want to update the link to another one? I cannot understand your actual situation. For example, do you want to just set the link only one time and you don't want to change the link?

Comment: I'm sorry buddy, but I don't think I can properly communicate to you what I actually want to happen. Your final sentence does seem pretty close to what I'd like to do though, but I don't want to further bother you about trying to set it up.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for your continual help, but I am not sure if I am making a mistake or the script doesn't work properly. It seems to run fine, but just not do anything, no error was caused when I didn't have an image on the first slide. The link also never applies to the image. Again, thanks for helping out.

Comment: I've also realized that I gave you the wrong idea of what the script should do, I misinterpreted, "do you want to just set the link only one time." I would prefer that the script continually change the slide page the link is set to, if possible.

Comment: Sorry that I sent a lot of messages, but I did get it working, I am grateful for your help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I would prefer that the script continually change the slide page the link is set to, if possible.`, in this case, how about executing the script by the time-driven trigger? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) Because in the case of Google Slides, the installable OnOpen trigger cannot be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your following reply,

> Your final sentence does seem pretty close to what I'd like to do though

I understood that you wanted to just set the link only one time and you don't want to change the link.

From your tag of `google-apps-script`, if you want to achieve this using a Google Apps Script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Slide and save the script. In this sample, the slide link of 5 or 6 pages is randomly set to an image of the 1st slide.

```js
function sample() {
  const links = [5, 6]; // Slide 5 and 6 are used as the links.

  const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length);
  const slides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();
  slides[0].getImages()[0].setLinkSlide(slides[links[idx] - 1]);
}
```

#### Note:

- If your 1st slide has no image, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.
- If the number of slides in your Google Slide is less than 6, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [setLinkSlide(slide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/image#setlinkslideslide)

Comment: Thanks very much for offering a solution and helping me out, I will try this out and see how it works.